# Probability of a language chain

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are 10 languages spoken at a conference, and 10 translators. Each translator can translate between exactly 2 of the 10 languages, with the 2 languages spoken by any translator being random and independent. Some translators may speak the same pair of languages. Using all 10 translators, what is the probability of being able to translate (directly or indirectly) between given languages A and B?

Comment: At a real conference, there would be a very high intentional correlation between the languages spoken by the translators. Presumably you're assuming that the languages spoken by the translators are independent? (And a minor quibble: The fact that the translators speak a language doesn't imply that they can translate it :-)

Comment: Could you provide some context? In particular, do you have reason to believe that this can be answered without a computer? It doesn't seem like it at first sight.

Comment: If a good upper bound would be good enough, you could obtain that from the expected number of such chains, which is much easier to calculate and should be quite close to the probability of at least one chain existing (since it's unlikely that several chains exist).

Comment: @joriki I have no reason to believe that this can be answered by hand. I just thought up the problem and thought it could be interesting.